# Split long SMS is concatenated wrongly on mobile ignoring the reference number

Tags: android, ios, sms, concatenation, smpp

I use [Cloudhopper](https://github.com/fizzed/cloudhopper-smpp) library to connect to [SMSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_service_center) and submit messages.
I split long message in a standard way:

- split text into small chunks of 134 bytes
- generate next *reference number*
- create [UDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Data_Header) 6 bytes with ref number
- send parts one by one

I have several connections open in *transceiver* mode to SMSC. If I use only one connection to send all the parts, then most of the time the messages are merged correctly both on Android 5.0.1 and iOS 8.4.1, though sometimes quite rarely the [*concatenated messages*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS) have the last part from the wrong message.

If I use different connections to send the parts, then most of the time messages are concatenated in a wrong way, usually the last part belongs to some other message. So it looks like mobiles don't honor the included reference number at all.

I know that if the *reference number* is the same and there are hanging old parts in the database on mobile then it might concatenate wrongly, but this doesn't seem to be the case in my tests since the *reference number* is sequential and controlled to be different for wrongly concatenated parts.

What could be the problem or how could I approach it?

Comment: For android, the sender, reference number and the total segment count is used to concatenate multiple segments into one message.

So either your client or your server are mixing up the segments. Do you already track the smpp packets you send to your server (using cloudhopper debugging or wireshark on network layer)?

Comment: Martin, thank you for the answer. In the end we figured, that actually the operator we are connecting to was recoding messages and messed up our reference numbers.